# Add css class to webpart cell

Tags: web-part, css

I'm developing my custom web part.
Code generated by SharePoint is below:

```
<div id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartctl00_ctl39_TestTile" class="s4-wpcell-plain ms-webpartzone-cell ms-webpart-cell-vertical ms-fullWidth ">
<div class="ms-webpart-chrome ms-webpart-chrome-vertical ms-webpart-chrome-fullWidth ">
    <div webpartid="94347657-e02b-4104-8033-26c64532ca77" haspers="false" id="WebPartctl00_ctl39_TestTile" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody noindex " allowdelete="false" allowexport="false" style="">
        <div id="ctl00_ctl39_Test" class="cssClassAddedFromCode">
            web part content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to add from code cssclass to root div with `Id = MSOZoneCell_WebPartctl00_ctl39_TestTile`.

When I try add my class during running method `AddAttributesToRender`:

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "cssClassAddedFromCode");
```

The cssclass goes to last div.

Comment: MSOZoneCell_WebPartctl00_ctl39_TestTile.Attributes.Add("class", "cssClassAddedFromCode")

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can not do that from your webpart. You could do it with jQuery or similar though!

```
jQuery('div[id$=TestTile]').addClass('cssClassAddedFromCode');
```

This script could be added to the page from your webpart by using ScriptManager

```
var addCssClassScript = "jQuery('div[id$=TestTile']').addClass('cssClassAddedFromCode');";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "AddCssClass", addCssClassScript, true);
```

and hence will be run when your webpart renders

Comment: I hoped I can do that from server code (for example: this.Parent.CssClass), and send to client well formatted markup.

Comment: Hopefully there is a way, but non that I know of

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using something called a Control Adapter.

Here are a couple of links to get you started

- [Removing Web Parts tables in SharePoint](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/removing-web-parts-tables-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Remove Web Part Zone table with Control Adapter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90030/add-css-class-to-webpart-cell)